# Using MathNet.Numerics to fit regression line through origin

Tags: c#, linear-regression, math.net

I have two double arrays (double[] XValues, YValues) which contain physiological data.

On these data I currently perform an 'unconstrained' linear regression using:

```
Tuple<double, double> r = Fit.Line(XValues, YValues);
double YIntercept = r.Item1;
double Slope = r.Item2;
```

There are sound (physiological) reasons for allowing the user to examine the line of best fit when regression through the origin is enforced.

How can this be done using MathNet?

Answer (score 2):

Beside of `Fit.Line` there is also a somewhat more generic `Fit.LinearCombination` function. Since the former essentially tries to find `p0` and `p1` in `y : x -> p0 * 1.0 + p1 * x`, it can also be written as `Fit.LinearCombination(XValues, YValues, x => 1.0, x => x)`.

You're looking for a line through the origin, where `p0` is forced to zero. Our equation thus simplifies to `y : x -> p1 * x`, which can be computed using `Fit.LinearCombination(XValues, YValues, x => x)`.